# Need a sample of Update/Add User in Powershell with GraphAPI

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Could I have a sampl of Update/Add User method in powershell with GraphAPI?
I have already tested below Get User script in my Tenant(B2C) ,
need to know the correct paramater usage for Update or ADD a user.
from Mircosoft documents, it seems doesn't have a Powershell with REST API sample of Update/Add user, only with SDK.

```
###############################GraphAPI Connect　@Start
$uri = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
 
$clinet_id = <>
$client_secret = <>
 
$queryURI = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>
 
#$scope = [System.Web.HTTPUtility]::UrlEncode(https://graph.microsoft.com/.default) 
$scope = https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
 
#Generating header values 
 
$tokenRequestQueryHeaderss =@{ 
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
} 
 
 
#Create body to pass when requesting access token 
 
$body = @{
    client_id=$($clinet_id)
    scope=$($scope)
    client_secret=$($client_secret)
    grant_type="client_credentials"
}
echo "#### body: " $body
 
#Send a post request to obtain bearer token 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $body -Method Post -Headers $tokenRequestQueryHeaderss 
 
Write-Host "#### tokenResult: "$result
###############################GraphAPI Connect　@End
 
###############################GraphAPI Data Collect
#Generate Header for query by adding Access Token obtained earlier 
$queryHeaders = @{ 
    Authorization = "Bearer $($result.access_token)" 
} 
 
echo "#### queryURI: " $queryURI
pause
 
#Send request  
 
$queryResult = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method Get -Headers $queryHeaders -Uri $queryURI -ContentType "application/json"
 
$queryResult
```

Comment: See following : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/gallery/?force_isolation=true&search=&filterBy=Users,Samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the user in MS graph using the powershell:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$params = @{
    BusinessPhones = @(
        "+1 425 555 0109"
    )
    OfficeLocation = "18/2111"
}

# A UPN can also be used as -UserId.
Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#example-1-update-properties-of-the-signed-in-user

To Add or create a user in MS Graph using the powershell:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$params = @{
    AccountEnabled = $true
    DisplayName = "Adele Vance"
    MailNickname = "AdeleV"
    UserPrincipalName = "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    PasswordProfile = @{
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = $true
        Password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    }
}

New-MgUser -BodyParameter $params
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#example-1-create-a-user

Hope this helps.